# Redirect to last visible activity of each module

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is it possible to redirect to last viewed activity of each module on module icon click.

In my application I have two modules with multiple activities.

When the user click first module it redirects to the activities say

(Application Home)->A->B->C.

If the user clicks home button which is provided in the 'C ' activity ,it will redirect to the (Application Home).

From second modules,it will redirect like

(Application Home)->D->E

And the user press home button in activity 'E' ,it will redirect to Application Home.
Is it possible to when the user clicks on each module it will redirect directly to last viewed activity of the module?

For example if the user click on first module it will redirect to activity C and from second module to activity 'E'.

Comment: It's possible .You can use SharedPreferences to store the name of last Activity .And when you click one module.Query the SharedPreferences,and skip a Activity by result of SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an idea, but may not be a right method, but you can solve this by tricky way. I gone through this same situation once, but i need to pass data in bundle also.

```
Lets go with module 1 : (Application Home)->A->B->C
```

From Home (data as bundle) > A (with bundle) > B(with bundle) > C . At last C got bundle data from B .

Here you used "HOME" button from C, it navigate to Home, There you need to set a Shared Preference value to identify ,from which Activity we navigate to Home. So here we set activity name C in prefs.

As per your scenario, while clicking the module button again , you need to navigate to C with bundle data right??

By clicking the module button> You need to check in prefs - last active Activity name we stored. > Without user navigation , by programmatically navigate to Activity C As same user acts (From Home (data as bundle) > A (with bundle) > B(with bundle) > C . At last C got bundle data from B).

Here whats the difference here it is navigation to each activity and bundle passing by a without knowing by user.

It may help you. If the trick works, accept this as answer.

Happy Coding !!